# How do I setup Kubernetes CIFS Persistent Volume PV Permissions for Bitnami Postgres Helm Deployment?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, grafana, persistent-volumes, cifs

I have a Kubernetes cluster that I am trying to deploy different Helm Charts, when charts have no persistence everything works great. When the Helm charts use persistent volumes I always run into permission issues. I am using a Windows file share CIFS with a persistent volume I created, Im using the [Secrets Store CSI Driver](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver/charts)

Here is my persistent volume and claim yaml, I have a secret (cifs-secret) with my username and password. For now I'm not using a storage class, just a manually created PV/PVC

```
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myvolume
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  mountOptions:
    - dir_mode=0777
    - file_mode=0777
    - uid=0998
    - gid=0996
    - mfsymlinks
    - nobrl
    - cache=none
    - domain=mydomain
  csi:
    driver: smb.csi.k8s.io
    readOnly: false
    volumeHandle: helmdata
    volumeAttributes:
      source: "//192.168.1.189/helm"
    nodeStageSecretRef:
      name: cifs-secret
      namespace: helm
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myclaim
  namespace: mynamespace
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  volumeName: cifs-helmtest-pv
```

This was failing for me until I figured out which user needed access to the volume, I'm using an IronBank Grafana image so I ran the image locally in Docker and shelled into it, from the command line typed more /etc/passwd and it at the end of the output it listed the uid:0998 and gid:0996. So I updated the volume yaml and added the - uid=0998 and - gid=0996 to the mount options.

Once this was in place I was able to successfully install the Bitnami Helm Chart, I did have to update the configmap.yaml in the templates directory to match the IronBank paths, these differ slightly from the Bitnami paths.

I have tried this same logic with the Bitnami Postgresql Helm Chart and I can't seem to get this working, when I shell into the container and run more /etc/passwd it is using uid:65543 and gid:65543 (nobody account) I created a volume with these uid/gids and I constantly get permission errors or incorrect permissions on directory, sometimes it will create the data folder in the volume mount location but its always empty.

[image]

The user account that create the windows share is the username and password I used in the cifs-secret.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of cluster do you use? Minikube, kubeadm or managed by cloud GKE, EKS, AKS? What version of kubernetes and helm do you use?

Comment: I've tried this on vanilla kubernetes clusters and now I'm trying it on a rancher desktop cluster (k3s)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this by using the Ironbank Postgres image with the Bitnami helm chart, I updated the UID and GID to 26 and set the volume information as follows...

[image]

Also, switching the data directory from the Bitnami default to /var/lib/postgresql/data is important to get the IronBank image to line up with the Bitnami chart.